# BigQuery - join tables as ARRAY of STRUCTs

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to join a table to the main one as a repeated record. I have a couple of solutions that work, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious that would allow me to perform the query without the need of specifying every column from the joined table to achieve the goal.

Given table A1:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |

And table A2:

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 25 |
| 6 | 30 |
| 8 | 40 |

I would like to see the following result:

| A | B | A2.B | A2.C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 10 |
|  |  | 2 | 15 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 20 |
|  |  | 4 | 25 |
| 3 | 6 | 6 | 30 |
| 4 | 8 | 8 | 40 |

Code that works:

```
WITH A1 AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS A, 4 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS A, 6 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS A, 8 AS B  
),
A2 AS 
(
  SELECT 10 AS C, 2 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15 AS C, 2 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 AS C, 4 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 25 AS C, 4 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30 AS C, 6 AS B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 40 AS C, 8 AS B
)

SELECT
  A1.A,
  A1.B,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(A2.B, A2.C)) A2
FROM A1
LEFT JOIN A2
ON A1.B = A2.B
GROUP BY A1.A, A1.B
```

What I would love to do is not having to specify each of the columns in the STRUCT like so:

```
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(A2.*)) A2
```

[Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."]

I can do this:

```
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(A2)) A2
```

But then instead of having columns A2.B and A2.C I get A2.A2.B and A2.A2.C

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below simple approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT
  ANY_VALUE(A1).*,
  ARRAY_AGG(A2) A2
FROM A1
LEFT JOIN A2
ON A1.B = A2.B
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', A1)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious ‍♂️, thank you!